# Binary timer in Assembly/Assembler language. Need some code improvement

Tags: assembly, pic

I'm trying to create binary timer using assembly language. There are 5 LED's in PORTA and 8 LED's in PORTB. I've made a code that output binary time in PORTB and when the register is full program starts over. How to improve my code that after PORTB has all 8 LED's on (register full) program keeps counting into A register (lights LED's in PORTA) and after all 13 LED's are on program starts over?

```
LIST   p=16F84                  
#INCLUDE  <p16F84a.inc>             
__CONFIG _XT_OSC & _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _CP_OFF       
Kint1 EQU 0Ch                       
ORG  0x000              
clrf  PORTA                         
clrf  PORTB                         
bsf  STATUS, 5                      
movlw  b'00000000'                  
movwf   TRISB                   
movlw   b'00000'                        
movwf  TRISA                        
movlw  b'00000111'                  
movwf OPTION_REG                    
bcf  STATUS, 5                  
;movlw  d'16'                       
;movlw  d'2'                        
movlw  d'80'                        
movwf  Kint1                        
Start1   movlw  d'11'                    
movwf  TMR0                         
Start2   btfss  INTCON,2        
goto  Start2                        
bcf INTCON,2                        
decfsz  Kint1,1                     
goto  Start1                     
incf  PORTB                         
;movlw  d'16'                       
;movlw  d'2'                        
movlw  d'80'                        
movwf   Kint1                       
goto  Start1                        
END
```

Comment: As it is, it's extremely hard to read your code. To get useful help, you should make it readable. Some line spacing, appropriate indentation, and comments would go a long way to helping you get an answer. Without having spent much time reading the code, it's not clear to me whether or not you've already made an attempt at extending the counting into the other LEDs.

Comment: This code is clear, I didn't make any changes to it. What I have tried is to create new loop start3 with similar content and make goto operation to start3 after PORTB is full. But I don't know that I've done wrong, time is running on both PORTA and PORTB in parallel...

Comment: "The code is clear" I strongly disagree. Reading someone else's unformatted assembly is very hard. I could figure out what's going on, but I'm not willing to invest the excess time into doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what the Original Poster asked for.

This example is crafted with the same level of comments as the Original Poster's.

```
    LIST    p=16F84a

#INCLUDE <p16F84a.inc>

    __CONFIG _XT_OSC & _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _CP_OFF

Kint1: EQU  0Ch

    ORG     0x000
    clrw
    tris    PORTA
    tris    PORTB
    movlw   0x07
    option
    clrf    PORTA
    clrf    PORTB
CountLoop:
    movlw   0x80
    movwf   Kint1
WaitLoop:
    movlw   0x0b
    movwf   TMR0
    bcf     INTCON,TMR0IF
WaitTMR0:
    btfss   INTCON,TMR0IF
    goto    WaitTMR0
    decfsz  Kint1,F
    goto    WaitLoop
    incfsz  PORTB,F
    goto    CountLoop
    incf    PORTA,F
    goto    CountLoop

    END
```